# Dates to Durations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I feel like this should be done very easily, yet I can't figure out how. I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with column **date**:

```
0    2012-08-21
1    2013-02-17
2    2013-02-18
3    2013-03-03
4    2013-03-04
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to have a columns of durations, something like:

```
0    0
1    80 days
2    1 day
3    15 days
4    1 day
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

My attempt yields bunch of 0 days and `NaT` instead:

```
>>> df.date[1:] - df.date[:-1]
0       NaT
1    0 days
2    0 days
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]:
0   2012-08-21
1   2013-02-17
2   2013-02-18
3   2013-03-03
4   2013-03-04
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [12]: s.diff()
Out[12]:
0        NaT
1   180 days
2     1 days
3    13 days
4     1 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [13]: s.diff().fillna(0)
Out[13]:
0     0 days
1   180 days
2     1 days
3    13 days
4     1 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 6):

`Timedeltas` are useful here: [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)

> Starting in v0.15.0, we introduce a new scalar type Timedelta, which is a subclass of datetime.timedelta, and behaves in a similar manner, but allows compatibility with np.timedelta64 types as well as a host of custom representation, parsing, and attributes.
>
> Timedeltas are differences in times, expressed in difference units, e.g. days, hours, minutes, seconds. They can be both positive and negative.

```
df

           0
0 2012-08-21
1 2013-02-17
2 2013-02-18
3 2013-03-03
4 2013-03-04
```

You could:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df)

TimedeltaIndex(['0 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
0      0
1    180
2      1
3     13
4      1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the difference between points in time using `.shift()` (or `.diff()` as illustrated by @Andy Hayden):

```
res = df-df.shift()
```

to get:

```
res.fillna(0)

         0
0   0 days
1 180 days
2   1 days
3  13 days
4   1 days
```

You can convert these from `timedelta64` `dtype` to `integer` using:

```
res.fillna(0).squeeze().dt.days

0      0
1    180
2      1
3     13
4      1
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.date[1:] - df.date[:-1]` doesn't do what you think it does. Each element is subtracted by series/dataframe index mapping, not by location in the series.

Calculating `df.date[1:] - df.date[:-1]` does:

```
+---- index of df.date[1:]
|                     +---- index of df.date[:-1]
|                     |
|                     v
v                     
                   -  0    2012-08-21    = NaT
1    2013-02-17    -  1    2013-02-17    = 0
2    2013-02-18    -  2    2013-02-18    = 0
3    2013-03-03    -  3    2013-03-03    = 0
4    2013-03-04    -                     = NaT
```